# Как изменить внесённые данные в бд?

Tags: c#, база-данных, telegram-bot

У меня есть телеграмм бот, при входе в него моментально в табличку вносится username и id пользователя, но остальные ячейки, к примеру name, остаются null.
Возможно-ли после окончания регистрации пользователя довнести в таблицу данные к его id и username?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Также вопрос, как можно изменить name в бд, если пользователь захотел его поменять? Как это осуществить без создания новой таблицы?

Comment: Читайте все эти вещи в документации к используемой вами бд

Comment: а какая у вас база данных используется?

Comment: Использую базу данных MAMP. Вопрос был связан скорее с кодом, нежели с бд

Comment: Изменение данных в бд очевидно связано с бд. Я никогда не слышал про базу данных MAMP, поэтому подозреваю, что вы путаетесь в терминах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня получилось сделать то, что я спрашивал через `UPDATE users SET name = 'Имя' WHERE tg_id = 'id user'`